# How can i fix glitch where ajax randomly does not update data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So what this script does is it takes the value inserted into a form in html and posts it to the ../Resources/BugReport.php file.  In that file, the values are inserted into a database, and then the ../Resources/BugDisplay.php file displays a table with the data from the database in it.

My glitch is that randomly, probably like 1/7 times the ajax does not update the table, and i have to reload the page for it to display.  I think the error is that the amount of time it takes for the data to be inserted into the database is longer that the amount of time that the script takes to update the BugDisplay table.

I know my code is redundant but its just my lame attempt to get rid of the glitch, i'm new to jquery.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.post('../Resources/BugDisplay.php',{},function(data){
                    $("#BugDisplay").html(data);
                });
            $("#sub").click(function(){
                var user_issue = $("#issue").val();
                var user_priority = $("#priority").val();
                var user_type = $("#type1").val();
                var user_author = $("#author").val();
                $.post("../Resources/BugReport.php",{issue:user_issue,priority:user_priority,type1:user_type,author:user_author},function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    //location.reload(true);
                });
                $.post('../Resources/BugDisplay.php',{},function(data){
                    $("#BugDisplay").html(data);
                });
            });
            $("#sub").click(function(){
                document.getElementById('issue').value='';
                $('#type1').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                $('#priority').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
                $.post('../Resources/BugDisplay.php',{},function(data){
                    $("#BugDisplay").html(data);
                });
            $.post('../Resources/BugDisplay.php',{},function(data){
                    $("#BugDisplay").html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to only perform the ajax on ready state '200', otherwise you'll be sending a new request while the other one is still working.

Comment: @GaryHayes i am not familiar with what ready state '200' means

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not returning the ajaxCall until after the data has been inserted into the database and returning the display code as the result of the BugReport call.

Comment: The reason i need to have an ajax call before the data is inserted is because otherwise the webpage will not display the table at all until data is inserted.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your workflow?

To me it sounds like you are doing this:

`form submit -> hit db -> return -> render -> hit display -> return -> render`


It should be:


`form submit -> hit db -> prepare display -> return -> render`

You would use a spinner or some animation while waiting for the ajaxCall to complete.

I do not understand why the 2nd workflow is not feasible.

Comment: so how do i prepare display?

Comment: Have a div hidden on the page that has a table structure or whatever your preference for showing data is.

When you hit your server and the DB calls completes, prepare JSON on the server in some specification you will have to define that defines the BugDisplay state.

Return that json as the result of that initial ajax call and then merge that data with your display template.

You don't need to confirm the form call was completed since showing that display will, by association, tell the user the call was successful.